# How to append to another df from inside a for loop

Tags: python

How can you append to an existing df from inside a for loop? For example:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as web

stocks = ['amc', 'aapl']
colnames = ['Datetime', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Adj Close', 'Volume', 'Name']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=colnames)
for stock in stocks:
    df = web.DataReader(stock,  'yahoo')
    df['Name'] = stock
```

What should I do next so that `df` is appended to  `df1`?

Comment: df1 is a list here, no?

Comment: Why would you import `data` as `web` - what good does that do, other than confuse everyone about what you're actually using there? (edit: looks like that's what the documentation suggests - still not a great idea) Why do you initalise `df1` as a list, instead of a DataFrame? Why do you try to set the `'name'` column of the DataFrame to `stock`? Did you try to rename the `'name'` column to the value of `stock` instead? It looks like the reader gets you a series, so you can just assign the series as a new column to the existing dataframe, once you create one.

Comment: @Grismar @enke I have changed `df1` to a dataframe.  The `name` is there just so it would be easier to see if the data had been appended. I did not understand this "so you can just assign the series as a new column to the existing dataframe" Could you please elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [pandas.concat()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=colnames)

for stock in stocks:
    df = web.DataReader(stock,  'yahoo')
    df['Name'] = stock
    df1 = pd.concat([df1, df], ignore_index=True)
```

Instead of concat dataframe in each loop, you could also try append dataframe to a list

```py
dfs = []
for stock in stocks:
    df = web.DataReader(stock,  'yahoo')
    df['Name'] = stock
    dfs.append(df)
df_ = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

```
print(df_)

            High         Low        Open       Close       Volume   Adj Close  Name
0      32.049999   31.549999   31.900000   31.549999    1867000.0   24.759203   amc
1      31.799999   30.879999   31.750000   31.000000    1225900.0   24.327585   amc
2      31.000000   30.350000   30.950001   30.799999     932100.0   24.170631   amc
3      30.900000   30.250000   30.700001   30.350000    1099000.0   23.817492   amc
4      30.700001   30.100000   30.549999   30.650000     782500.0   24.052916   amc
...          ...         ...         ...         ...          ...         ...   ...
2515  179.009995  176.339996  176.690002  178.960007  100589400.0  178.960007  aapl
2516  179.610001  176.699997  178.550003  177.770004   92633200.0  177.770004  aapl
2517  178.029999  174.399994  177.839996  174.610001  103049300.0  174.610001  aapl
2518  174.880005  171.940002  174.029999  174.309998   78699800.0  174.309998  aapl
2519  174.880005  171.940002  174.029999  174.309998   78751328.0  174.309998  aapl

[2520 rows x 7 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do won't quite work, since the data retrieved by DataReader has several columns and you need that data for several stocks. However, each of those columns is a time series.

So what you probably want is something that looks like this:

```
Stock       amc
Field       High       Low        Open  ...
2022-03-30  29.230000  25.350000  ...
2022-03-31  25.920000  23.260000  ...
2022-04-01  25.280001  22.340000  ...
2022-04-01  25.280001  22.340000  ...
...
```

And you'd be able to access like `df[('amc', 'Low')]` to get a time series for that stock, or like `df[('amc', 'Low')]['2022-04-01'][0]` to get the 'Low' value for 'amc' on April 1st.

This gets you exactly that:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as web

stocks = ['amc', 'aapl']
df = pd.DataFrame()
for stock_name in stocks:
    stock_df = web.DataReader(stock_name, data_source='yahoo')
    for col in stock_df:
        df[(stock_name, col)] = stock_df[col]
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.columns, names=['Stock', 'Field'])

print(f'\nall data:\n{"-"*40}\n', df)

print(f'\none series:\n{"-"*40}\n', df[('aapl', 'Volume')])

print(f'\nsingle value:\n{"-"*40}\n', df[('amc', 'Low')]['2022-04-01'][0])
```

The solution uses a `MultiIndex` to achieve what you need. It first loads all the data as retrieved from the API into columns labeled with tuples of stock name and field, and it then converts that into a proper `MultiIndex` after loading completes.

Output:

```
all data:
----------------------------------------
 Stock             amc             ...         aapl            
Field            High        Low  ...       Volume   Adj Close
Date                              ...                         
2017-04-04  32.049999  31.549999  ...   79565600.0   34.171505
2017-04-05  31.799999  30.879999  ...  110871600.0   33.994480
2017-04-06  31.000000  30.350000  ...   84596000.0   33.909496
2017-04-07  30.900000  30.250000  ...   66688800.0   33.833969
2017-04-10  30.700001  30.100000  ...   75733600.0   33.793839
...               ...        ...  ...          ...         ...
2022-03-29  34.330002  26.410000  ...  100589400.0  178.960007
2022-03-30  29.230000  25.350000  ...   92633200.0  177.770004
2022-03-31  25.920000  23.260000  ...  103049300.0  174.610001
2022-04-01  25.280001  22.340000  ...   78699800.0  174.309998
2022-04-01  25.280001  22.340000  ...   78751328.0  174.309998

[1260 rows x 12 columns]

one series:
----------------------------------------
 Date
2017-04-04     79565600.0
2017-04-05    110871600.0
2017-04-06     84596000.0
2017-04-07     66688800.0
2017-04-10     75733600.0
                 ...     
2022-03-29    100589400.0
2022-03-30     92633200.0
2022-03-31    103049300.0
2022-04-01     78699800.0
2022-04-01     78751328.0
Name: (aapl, Volume), Length: 1260, dtype: float64

single value:
----------------------------------------
 22.34000015258789
```